# Does concatening $5^n$ and $31^n$ ever lead to a prime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

If we concatenate the numbers $5^n$ and $31^n$ , where $n\ge 1$ is an integer, then we get the number $$a_n:=5^n\cdot 10^m+31^n$$ where $m$ is the number of digits in the decimal expansion of $31^n$

> Is $a_n$ prime for some $n\ge 1$ ?

I checked upto $n=10^4$ without finding a prime.

Comment: For odd $n$, $a_n$ is a multiple of $3$. For $n\equiv 2\pmod 4$, $a_n$ is a multiple of $13$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, for $n=8$ the factorization (if I entered the correct number) turns out to be $106129\times3680670249329$, so it seems unlikely there's any simple rule for the remaining case(s).

Comment: @BarryCipra You entered it correctly.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The statement about $n \equiv 2$ mod $4$ is false.  First counterexample is $n = 118$.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be any obvious reason it should not be prime.  Heuristically, the probability of a "random" integer $x$ being prime is approximately $1/\log(x)$, and $\log(a_n) \approx n \log (5\cdot 31)$.
Since the series $\sum_n 1/n$ diverges, we should expect infinitely many $a_n$ to be prime.  But this is not a proof.